# Multiple Swift Storyboard Project using the same XIB

Tags: swift, storyboard

I have multiple different swift projects using Storyboard, all of these projects use a couple of screens that are identical, both view and the controller behind.

Now its easy enough to use same viewcontroller, in all these projects however is there a way i can use the same xib in the Storyboard?

Ideally I want to use the same xib file for all projects so I only have to modify them once, not copy paste.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well you can always copy (Command + C) a ViewController XIB in a Storyboard and then paste (Command + V) into other Storyboard project. You can also select multiple ones by (Command + Clicking) or dragging and copy multiple ones. I hope this is what you are asking.